# Firebase Instant User Disable?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

How to instant disable any logged in User to **force logout or prevent from using any service** in **Android or Web App** using Firebase Admin SDK?

I have already tried disabling user using firebase Admin SDK but that only prevent from new login but if user already logged in they don't do any thing ?

```
admin.auth().updateUser("uid", {
    disabled: true,
  });
```

Kindly Provide a way to instant disable already logged in user form using any service in Mobile or Web.

Comment: The user's token will be valid for 1 hour after the user signs in.  Disabling the account does not change the validity of that token.  You will have to wait for that 1 hour to elapse, or somehow notify the app code to force it to sign the user out so they can't sign back in.  There are no workarounds to this - it's just the way it works.

Comment: Actually, the documentation contains a recipe how you can communicate token revocation to the client through the Firebase Realtime Database: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation